# How Do I Add Display Name To An Inherited Property With EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, metadata

I have a class Movement inheriting from TimeBlock. TimeBlock is provided for me and I can't change it. TimeBlock provides a DurationDescription property and I want to display it. However I always use LabelFor etc which means I need to have Display metadata on DurationDescription so I can have "Duration Desc." etc.

How do I add metadata to an inherited class with EF Code First. Am I supposed to use buddy metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the [MetadataTypeattribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx). It will work fine also with inheritance like with partial classes:

```
public class Base
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ClassMetadata))]
public class Class : Base
{
    [DisplayName("My prop 2")]
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    class ClassMetadata
    {
        [DisplayName("My prop 1")]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On the UI the properties will be displayed as `"My prop 1"` and `"My prop 2"`.

Comment: Cool thought I may be supposed to do it some other way with code first. I'd used metadata typeof in normal EF.